# Unable to open pdf Adobe Acrobat DC

Tags: pdf, file-permissions, adobe-acrobat

I have a user who can't open a couple of .pdf files.

The word docs the files were original created from can be opened fine and you can open the pdfs in every other application except Adobe Acrobat DC.The file says you can't open it because you don't have permission. Files created before and after them have worked fine.

I have tried re-saving the files

Reinstalling Adobe DC

Checked file permissions

This effects all users (trying to access the specific files)

OS : W10
Office 365 (16)
Lenovo 500GB HDD 16GB RAM

Comment: Did you try to open and re-save the files using another Adobe application, like Photoshop or Illustrator?

Comment: @spike_66 yes we have, it's really strange